# Oauth.io and Ripple InAppBrowser Emulation

Tags: cordova, oauth, ionic-framework, ripple, oauth.io

I am making a mobile app with Cordova and I use [oauth.io](https://oauth.io/getting-started?phonegap) to connect with facebook.

It is working just fine when I deploy my app to my Samsung Galaxy S5 phone.

However, when running my app in debug with Ripple, I get this screen when oauth calls facebook.

[image: in app browser error]

I tryed to use the oauth.io browser javascript file ( it displays browser version correctly when I start the app) but still get the error.

Also tryed to Add the InAppBrowser plugin in my project's config.

edit : here is a more detailed error I just found in the console.

[image]

Comment: Are you running chrome with the flag --disable-web-security ?

Answer (score 1):

I found using Ripple broke many of the ngCordova Plugins, I'd strongly suggest using one of the following for testing:

**Terminals:**
ionic serve
ionic serve --lab

or push the app to [Ionic View](http://view.ionic.io/):

**Terminals:**
ionic upload

and use the [Ionic View](http://view.ionic.io/) app on your handheld device, ideal for **IOS**.

I hope this helps and Good luck.

Comment: wow, that was so easy and awesome. love this Ionic View solution.